# Handling Done and next of SoftKeypad in android?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a simple login Activity having two edit texts fileds, for username and password.. Now I want to achieve following two features,

1. If **next** button is touched while focus is on userNameText, the **cursor should move** to the second editText field i.e. passwordText..
2. If **done** is pressed while cursor is on passwordText field the, I want to **call a function** which is called inside the **OK** Button's listener.

[image]               [image]

My XML file looks like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/online" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userNamelbl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/userNameLbl" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userNametxt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/userNamelbl"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:hint="@string/userNameTxt"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/passwordtxt"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/passwordlbl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/userNametxt"
        android:text="@string/passwordLbl" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordtxt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/passwordlbl"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:hint="@string/passwordTxt"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/okBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/passwordtxt"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:text="@string/okLbl" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/okBtn"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/okBtn"
        android:text="@string/cancelLbl" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have not done anything extra on my edittext's and next button changes focus automatically.

Comment: Checked again... but unfortunately that doesn't work, next is doing nothing... can u paste your XML code as an answer to this question so that I can compare...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requested by anDroider - Not an answer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/loginuser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/username_string"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >

        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/loginpass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/password_string"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Login" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: This part is an answer

Use `OnEditorActionListener` and listen for the done key to be pressed.